# What is the scheme-specific part in a URI?

Tags: java, url, uri, url-scheme

I can't find any explanation as to what exactly the "scheme-specific part" of a URI is.

Comment: In my case the URI class in Java.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) :

> All URIs and absolute URI references are formed with a scheme name,
> followed by a colon character (":"), and the remainder of the URI
> called (in the outdated RFCs 1738 and 2396, but not the current STD
> 66/RFC 3986) **the scheme-specific part**.

The scheme-specific-part is what you have after the `:`.

Example :

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077453/
scheme  :   scheme-specific-part
```

Answer (score 1):

Each URI begins with a scheme name that refers to a specification for assigning identifiers within that scheme.  As such, the URI syntax is a federated and extensible naming system wherein each scheme's specification may further restrict the syntax and semantics of identifiers using that scheme.

See this section of the URI rfc https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1

Answer (score 1):

Scheme specific means just to simple define which Protocol is used by the Url like 
HTTP or HTTPS .
So simply add these in URL to work fine
Scheme Specific
http://localhost:8080/api/notes

Without Scheme
localhost:8080/api/notes